# Error 1054 mysql syntax error uknown column

Tags: php, mysql

There's something wrong with my mysql code, but I don't know what.

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
mysql_select_db("cursussite");

function countUser ($cursus)
{
    $sql = ("SELECT COUNT AS cursus FROM cursisten WHERE cursus = $cursus") or die (mysql_error());
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $data = mysql_fetch_row($query) or die (mysql_error());

if ($data > 5){

    echo "Alle plaatsen zijn bezet.";
}

else {
    echo "Er zijn nog " . $data . "beschikbaar";
    }

?>
```

I want to create a function where i can count the courses (cursus)
But if i execute the code, i will get this error. 
"#1054 - Unknown column 'COUNT' in 'field list'"

Can someone help me?

---

I still can't get it working. :( Feeling really stupid. 
I know I have to change the column name to Totalcursus 
but what do I have to put in the If-Else statement?

Code:

```
if ($data> 5){

    echo "Alle plaatsen zijn bezet.";


    }

else {
    echo "Er zijn nog " .$data. " plaatsen beschikbaar";
}
```

But the output on the website is:

```
Alle plaatsen zijn bezet.
```

The strange thing is that I only got 2 records in the database, so it should give me

```
Er zijn nog $data plaatsen beschikbaar right?
```

Comment: add a parameter to the COUNT function => COUNT(user) for example

Comment: Always nice to encounter a Dutch speaking coder on StackOverflow. One remark, in your last `echo` statement, there should be a space before `beschikbaaar` otherwise it would print Èr zijn nog 20beschikbaar. ,Also, you might want to look at [sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), it helps a lot when putting variables into strings.

Answer (score 2):

Use `count(*)` to count the records and put your `$cursus` variable in quotes if it is a string

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cursus 
FROM cursisten 
WHERE cursus = '$cursus'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need use `count(*)` function, since you have already `cursus` coulmn, if use the same column for count, it conflicts.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Totalcursus FROM cursisten WHERE cursus = '".$cursus."' ";
$query = mysql_query($sql)  or die (mysql_error());
```

**COUNT(*) vs COUNT(col) REF:** http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/